# Rails autosave gives double validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4.2.

I have four models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :licenses
end

class License < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user #, autosave: true
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :licenses
end
```

Then I have code which looks something like this to create a `License` for a user:

```
def user
  @_user ||= User.find(...)
end

def create_license
  license = License.find_or_initialize_by(application: @application, user: user)

  if license.user.organization.nil?
    license.user.organization = @organization
  end

  if license.user.organization == @organization
    license.expires_on = nil
    license.save
  else
    license.errors.add(:user, "User belongs to different organization")
  end

  license
end
```

The problem with this code is that when I run `license.save` it does not save the `user` object, i.e. the organization is not changed.

So I added `belongs_to :user, autosave: true` to the `License` class to force it to save the user as well. This works ok in this case.

However, if I have the `autosave` option set and run code like this:

```
user = User.new
user.licenses.build(...)
user.save
```

The user object gets each validation error twice.

Am I doing something weird?

Comment: Mh no, rails saves only the model you call save on, you are referencing a model of a model of a model, it doesn't know it needs to save that too unless you explicitly tell it to do so, with autosave or manually calling save. That being said, validation errors twice looks like a bug. Did you try looking for something on rails github repository?

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL Thank you. I mixed up  my problems a bit, please see the last section of my original question. I updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Rails, see: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20874

Answer (score 0):

You should remove autosave: true from the belongs_to. 
it will automatically save the license as well. 
As you have added autosave. it is running validations two times

Comment: But then the example in my original post is not working.

Comment: as your license belongs to user. so on saving user, it will also save license, but you are trying to do the other way round that wont work, license can belong to other things as well so why save user on creating license. i hope it makes sense.

Comment: You mean I should try to create the license through the user object instead?

Comment: yes. license = user.licenses.new. this way when you do user.save it will save user as well as license. and on license.save, it will save license.